# Output value error in shell Script Python

Tags: python, shell

I have a Python program in which I have used a shell script which returns an output value.Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys

filename=input("Enter the filename:")
val=subprocess.check_output(['bash','./grep.sh',filename])
print(val)
```

grep.sh code:

```
file=$1
grep -c "^[0-9]" $file
```

My Output:

```
Enter the filename:lg.txt
b'4\n'
```

As you can see it prints result as `b'4\n'` instead of printing only the value `4`

What is wrong with my code ? How to rectify this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in your code

- the `b` prefix is for bytes, to get the strict value from the terminal
- the `\n` is just because that is what returned in th terminal, this is the new line at the end

No matter the command, you'll to do this when retrieving frmo a command

```
val = subprocess.check_output(['bash','./grep.sh',filename])
result = val.decode('utf-8').rstrip() # decode in UTF-8 then remove newline char
```